# Resample list of lat lon points

Tags: python-3.x, gis, cartopy, metpy

The code below reads in data about the location of valid ASOS (weather observing stations) around the globe. I'd like to use the list in the future as a list of points to plot data from, but a lot of the stations are way too close together to view at a national or even state-level scale. I'd like to reduce the density of the stations that are plotted on the map. Below is some code that plots all the stations in the US/southern Canada:

```
import re

fh = open('../498/stations.txt', 'r')
lines = fh.readlines()

data = []
for line in lines:
    comment_match = re.search('^!', line)
    blank_match = re.search('^\s*$', line)
    header_match = re.search('\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{2}|CD\s+STATION', line)
    if comment_match or blank_match or header_match:
        None
    else:
        ICAO = line[20:24].strip()
        if len(ICAO) == 4:
            CD = line[0:3].strip()
            if len(CD) == 0:
                CD = None
            STATION = line[3:20].strip()
            LATLON = line[39:54]
            if LATLON[5] == 'S':
                LAT = float("{0:.2f}".format(-(float(LATLON[0:2])+float(LATLON[3:5])/60.)))
            if LATLON[5] == 'N':
                LAT = float("{0:.2f}".format((float(LATLON[0:2])+float(LATLON[3:5])/60.)))
            if LATLON[14] == 'W':
                LON = float("{0:.2f}".format(-(float(LATLON[8:11])+float(LATLON[12:14])/60.)))
            if LATLON[14] == 'E':
                LON = float("{0:.2f}".format((float(LATLON[8:11])+float(LATLON[12:14])/60.)))
            ELEV = int(line[54:59].strip())
            C = line[81:-1]
            stn_dict = {'name':STATION, 'id':ICAO, 'state':CD, 'country':C, 'lat':LAT, 'lon':LON, 'elev':ELEV}
            data.append(stn_dict)

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

extent = [-130,-60,20,60]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection=ccrs.Miller())
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('50m'))
ax.set_extent(extent,crs=ccrs.Miller())

for stndict in data:
    if stndict['lon'] > extent[0] and stndict['lon'] < extent[1] and stndict['lat'] > extent[2] and stndict['lat'] < extent[3]:
        plt.plot(stndict['lon'], stndict['lat'], color='blue', marker='o',
         transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

[Here is the output of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADQvu.png)
You can see that many plot on top of one another at this map scale. Ideally, I would like to have functionality to change the distance between points plotted, say 100km for instance.

Are there any libraries that would make this task easier?

Comment: Matplotlib Basemap has `hexbin` plot that shows density of points occurences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MetPy](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy) has a function [`reduce_point_density`](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.reduce_point_density.html) that can do what you want. This function takes your station locations as a (number of points) x dimensions (e.g. 2 or 3) array, along with a radius, the minimum distance to the nearest point in the result. The result is a boolean array that you can use as a mask to select the points of interest. You use it like:

```
from metpy.calc import reduce_point_density
import numpy as np
point_locs = np.array([(10, 50), (11, 49), (35, 40)])
mask = reduce_point_density(point_locs, 4.)
keep_points = point_locs[mask]
```

You can also optionally pass an array of priority values, which allows controlling which points are preferentially selected to be kept. An bigger example using `reduce_point_density` is [here](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/examples/plots/Station_Plot.html).